# remotely and programatically logoff an active domain user

Tags: .net, active-directory, logoff

I need to be able to logoff any user from his windows session from a program.

I know I could log in as an admin and force a remote logoff. Is there any other way to force a logoff without logging in?

The tool will run as admin so that's not a problem, being able to remote logoff without logging in is.

Tool is in .NET, but any other way is welcome (JScript, command line tool to run from PInvoke, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps with Sysinternals' [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx), particularly [PsShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx)?

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out this script in this page: http://www.robvanderwoude.com/files/logoff_vbs.txt

I decided to store it as a string inside the tool and make it write it to disk, execute it and delete it. Not particularly elegant (yes, yes, ugly as hell), but good enough for now.

```
' Logoff.vbs, Version 1.00
' Logoff current user on any WMI enabled computer on the network
'
' Adapted from posts by Alex Angelopoulos on www.developersdex.com
' and Michael Harris on microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript
'
' Written by Rob van der Woude
' http://www.robvanderwoude.com

' Check command line parameters
Select Case WScript.Arguments.Count
    Case 0
        ' Default is local computer if none specified
        strComputer = "."
    Case 1
        Select Case WScript.Arguments(0)
            ' "?", "-?" or "/?" invoke online help
            Case "?"
                Syntax
            Case "-?"
                Syntax
            Case "/?"
                Syntax
            Case Else
                strComputer = WScript.Arguments(0)
        End Select
    Case Else
        ' More than 1 argument is not allowed
        Syntax
End Select

' Define some constants that can be used in this script;
' logoff = 0 (no forced close of applications) or 5 (forced);
' 5 works OK in Windows 2000, but may result in power off in XP
Const EWX_LOGOFF   = 0
Const EWX_SHUTDOWN = 1
Const EWX_REBOOT   = 2
Const EWX_FORCE    = 4
Const EWX_POWEROFF = 8

' Connect to computer
Set OpSysSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{(Shutdown)}//" & strComputer & "/root/cimv2").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where Primary=true")

' Actual logoff
for each OpSys in OpSysSet
    OpSys.Win32Shutdown EWX_LOGOFF
next

' Done
WScript.Quit(0)


Sub Syntax
msg = vbCrLf & "Logoff.vbs,  Version 1.00" & vbCrLf & _
      "Logoff the current user of any WMI enabled computer on the network." & _
      vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Usage:  CSCRIPT  LOGOFF.VBS  [ computer_name ]" & _
      vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "Where:  " & Chr(34) & "computer_name" & Chr(34) & _
      "  is the name of the computer to be logged off" & vbCrLf & _
      "                         (without leading backslashes); default is " & _
      Chr(34) & "." & Chr(34) & vbCrLf & _
      "                         (the local computer)." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "Written by Rob van der Woude" & vbCrLf & _
      "http://www.robvanderwoude.com" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "Based on posts by Alex Angelopoulos on www.developersdex.com" & _
      vbCrLf & _
      "and Michael Harris on microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript" & vbCrLf
Wscript.Echo(msg)
Wscript.Quit(1)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use simple command line to logoff forcefully from any remote user  as below

```
C:\>psexec \\remotepc shutdown /f /l
```